# Select com data maior de 20 anos

Tags: sql-server

Como fazer um select com **data do pedido** maior que **20 anos**?

```
Select * 
from Pedidos
Where dataPedido > ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select * 
from Pedidos
Where dataPedido > DATEADD (yy, -20, GETDATE());
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186819(v=sql.120).aspx).