# Sql Query, buscar dados a partir de ID determinado

Tags: php, sql, query

como fazer uma consulta, buscando dados a partir do ID determinado?

Por exemplo, minha tabela tem 1mil registros, eu quero determinar num foreach a busca dos dados a partir do registro 300.

Comment: Não acho que cabe uma resposta, essa pergunta deve possuir duplicata, `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id > 300`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Select com data maior de 20 anos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132011/select-com-data-maior-de-20-anos) @MarceloBonifazio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você gostaria de pegar registros num intervalo, você poderia esta utilizando por exemplo o `OFFSET` e `LIMIT`

`SELECT coluna FROM tabela ORDER BY id LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;`

Neste caso, você poderá utilizar o `OFFSET` para determinar qual seria o id de inicio e o `LIMIT` para determinar quanto registros você que deseja.

O exemplo acima irá retornar os id's de 11 a 20.

Espero ter ajudado.

Referência:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Exato. Na sua pergunta voce confunde o ID, que normalmente está relacionado a uma chave primária, com um indicador da posiçao do registro, ou um cursor.